# $S_n = \max\limits_k\{X_i = X_n, \forall i = n − 1, . . . , n − k + 1\}$ is a Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

> Let $(X_n)_{n≥1}$ be i.i.d random variables such that $X_1 ∼
> Binom(r,p)$. Prove or refute that we have a Markov
>   chain, and in the affirmative case give the state space and the transition matrix.

The length of the current run of equal values, that is,

$S_n = \max\limits_k\{X_i = X_n,  \forall i = n − 1, . . . , n − k + 1\}$

What I got,

State space is $\mathbb N$

Abbreviate $P(X_i=k)=\binom{r}{k}p^k(1-p)^{r-k}=:p_k$ then,

$S_{n+1}=\begin{cases} 
      S_n, &\text{if}\  X_{n+1}\neq X_{n} \\
      S_n+1, &\text{if}\    X_{n+1}= X_{n}
   \end{cases}$

$P(S_{n+1}=j|S_n=i)=p_{ij}=\begin{cases} 
      \sum\limits_{k=0}^r p^2_k, &\text{if}\   j=i+1 \\
      1-\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^r p^2_k\right),&\text{if}\    j=1\\
0,& otherwise
   \end{cases}$

It looks terrible, can this be correct ?